last year of school - UK visit visa
so I've visited the UK once with my mother when I was 17 years old. (we're egyptians so we need a visa)
we plan to visit the UK again next year but by that time I'd be 18 years old and in the last year of highschool. my question is, does me being 18 and in the last year of highschool pose a bad chance of approval for my next visa? my mother will apply with me again next time too. if my mother visa gets accepted would this improve my chances for my decision? and should we apply for 2 year visit visa? or 6 month one due to my age as I don't want to waste money on a low chance 2 year visa. this would be the 3rd time my mother applies for a visa and my 2nd time.

Do you have a particular reason for wanting a 2 year validity visitor visa?

travel wise: yearly tourism with my mum. personally, I don't want to go through the stressful visa process everytime, but they would still issue a 6 month visa even if I apply for a 2 year visit visa but don't qualify for it correct?

They’ll issue the visa they conclude that you qualify for. If they think that asking for a 2 year visa is indicative of an intention to overstay or otherwise break UK immigration rules, they’ll refuse the application.

I see, thank you

Your circumstances at 18 are surely very different to your mother’s. Can’t see that her getting a visa will necessarily improve your chances. You are at the age when folk often migrate for economic reasons. She is not. Each application may stand or fall on separate merits.

wouldn't it be a little better in my case since I'd be travelling with my own mother and also dependent on her. and have went to the UK before plus I'd technically be in education still (last year of school)?

You have to demonstrate that you intend to leave after your visit. What firm plans have you got for the future? Can you show documentary evidence? For example, enrolment at a university in Egypt.

unfortunately I wouldn't have any university documentary, as by the time I apply I would still have a few months left till I graduate. so I'm still a school student therefore I cannot get any university enrollment documentary without graduating from school first.
wouldn't it make sense that since I'm travelling with my mother for a 2nd time a whole year later show that I'm just going on a vacation with my mother again in summer? I've went with her to the UK a few months ago and want to again next year. by the time I go again, I would have just turned 18 but that wouldn't mean I'm independant

bare in mind too, my own mother would be my sponsor and she'll be travelling with me. so I suppose this should help?

and also wouldn't good travel history of my mother reflect on me well?

@Hellomsm Wouldn’t it make sense to vacation elsewhere rather than return to the UK? Why the desire to return relatively soon? Repeat visits could look as if you’re trying to build up a life in the UK.

@Traveller not soon, this is like 12-13 months later. I just loved the UK so I want to have another vacation in it
